# How to replace exit() from a C++ library to Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp, cgal

In the C++ library CGAL there are these lines:

```cpp
    void            exit( Locate_type& lt, int& li, int& lj ) const
    {
      lt = prev_lt(); li = prev_li(); lj = prev_lj();
    }
    std::tuple<Locate_type, int, int> exit() const
    {
      return { prev_lt(), prev_li(), prev_lj() };
    }
```

In order to port CGAL to R, the author of **RcppCGAL** has done the following modification:

```cpp
    std::tuple<Locate_type, int, int> Rcpp::stop("Exit error") const
    {
      return { prev_lt(), prev_li(), prev_lj() };
    }
```

Previously, this worked. But now, CRAN has upgraded **gcc** and this doesn't work anymore. This error appears:

```
At global scope:
/data/gannet/ripley/R/test-dev/RcppCGAL/include/CGAL/Triangulation_segment_traverser_3.h:371:49: 
error: expected identifier before string constant
   371 |     std::tuple<Locate_type, int, int>Rcpp::stop("Exit Error") const
       |                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/data/gannet/ripley/R/test-dev/RcppCGAL/include/CGAL/Triangulation_segment_traverser_3.h:371:49: 
error: expected ',' or '...' before string constant
/data/gannet/ripley/R/test-dev/RcppCGAL/include/CGAL/Triangulation_segment_traverser_3.h:371:38: 
error: invalid use of '::'
   371 |     std::tuple<Locate_type, int, int>Rcpp::stop("Exit Error") const
       |                                      ^~~~
```

What should we do?

Comment: Commonly we use an old school way with an editor, or `#define` statement, to ensure to `exit()` or `abort()` remains.  I think the CRAN check look for actual linker symbols but _maybe_ the `grep` finds your string.  You could try to reword.  The check is in R's code so you be able to check with a "before" and "after" your changes.  (Also, this is not an Rcpp question but mostly an R-packaging-with-C++-source-code question but happy to help...)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Sorry I don't understand what you mean. What should we `#define`?

Comment: The first step in addressing a CRAN request of 'please change' is to duplicate it locally.  Once you have done that you can work through alternatives.  The policy requirement here is old: R as an interactive system cannot have `exit()` or `abort()`.  If you think this is a false positive due to a newer compiler, I fear you will have to prove that it is and / or still work around it.

Comment: Stephane the question is irreproducible.  The snippets above are incomplete.   Should we just delete this?  Or else improve it so that it becomes a question?   The signature shown is clearly not one compatible with `.Call()` and hence an R interface.  Would this be better as an email between you and the RcppCGAL maintainer?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel CRAN sent an email to both me and the author of **RcppCGAL**. But currently he is not available.

Comment: I don't see how to make the question reproducible, except by trying to install one of my packages with this new **gcc**.

Comment: You could start with sufficiently self-contained file snippets, maybe with an include to the CGAL header.  Currently it is equivalent to a 'picture' and that strikes me as a question we should probably delete,  (You have a bit of a tendency to file question and not come back, I think one can do better as SO can be a bit of a 'wiki' so to speak.)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel The problem is that I'm totally lost. [Here is the file](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Triangulation_3/include/CGAL/Triangulation_segment_traverser_3.h) in question. But I don't which code runs this file.

Comment: Which gcc version was that?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel gcc 13.2, a minor update released last week. Here are the changes: <https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-13/changes.html>.

Comment: It is fairly easy to get access to that version. Docker is a helpful here. Debian has 13.1 and 13.2 in testing and unstable, respectivelt.  Ubuntu has it in the version I am running (23,04) though not in the LTS version you may find at cloud providers.  rhub / rhub2 may have it too.

Answer (score 2):

Here is educated guess.  Someone, possible via a mechanical replament, reaction to a function entitled `exit()` by somewhat blindly replacing `exit()` with `Rcpp::stop().

The idea was to replace, and I use a hyopthetical example

```
void checkAndExit(int a, int b) {
     if (a > b) exit();
}
```

with

```
void checkAndExit(int a, int b) {
     if (a > b) Rcpp::stop("Exit on comparison);
}
```

But that is not whwt we have here.  Maybe all it takes is to replace

```
std::tuple<Locate_type, int, int> exit() const {
  return { prev_lt(), prev_li(), prev_lj() };
}
```

with, say,

```
std::tuple<Locate_type, int, int> myExitFunc() const {
  return { prev_lt(), prev_li(), prev_lj() };
}
```

and replace the calls to `exit()` with `myExitFunc()` to avoid the false positive over CRAN not liking calls to `exit()`.

You may also get with namespaces.  CRAN clearly looks for the C-level 'global' one `::exit()`.

I could be wrong, but you seem stuck so it was worth a try.

Comment: Thanks ! I will wait for Eric Dupinace to give a try.

Comment: Any follow-up on this, Stephane?  Questions age better here if you tend to them a llitle with extra information and possible follow-ups.

Comment: Dirk> Unfortunatey, no sign from Eric Dupinace. CRAN will shut down the packages :-(

Comment: Looks like someone found a solution: https://github.com/ericdunipace/RcppCGAL/issues/11#issuecomment-1712655897

Comment: That looks like a more sensible fix than the ham-fisted character replacement of `exit()` with `Rcpp::stop()` where it wasn't a function.  Tyler is correct that the _false positive_ on the CRAN side needs a workaround.  Good stuff.

Comment: Indeed, it works!!

Comment: Yay. So a whole set of CGAL using packages may be coming back to CRAN?  Nice!!

Comment: I hope so. There is a new "significant warning" during the compilation of **cgalMeshes**. :-(